# Do Xamarin support Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a requirement to create app using xamarin and cloud firestore, but i am not able to find related documents anywhere. do really xamarin forms supports firebase cloud store, if yes please send me related link for connectivity and basic crud operation.

Comment: Do you want to use googleDrive? The google api .net client library does not support Xamarin .So you can not implement it in forms.But it is available in xamarin.ios and xamarin.android.You can download it from nuget .https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.iOS/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I want to use cloud firestore database to store my data. do it support Xamarin?

Comment: Yes.for iOS https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore/ and for android  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT sure, need to check and will inform you if it is correct. just need some time.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Is there no library by which i can create one code base for iOS and Android to connect to cloud firestore.

Comment: Firesotore is unavailable in xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 5):

"Absolutely yes!"

There is a very useful plugin for Xamarin Forms (Android and iOS):

[Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore)

**How to use?**

1. Create a new Firebase project:

[image]

Follow the steps to put a name for your project and enable Analytics.

2. In your Firebase project create an Android application and download the file generated (google-services.json)

[image]
[image]

3. In your Firebase project create an iOS application and download the file generated (GoogleService-Info.plist).

[image]
[image]

4. In your Xamarin Forms Android project (YourProject.Android) paste the file google-services.json in the main folder

[image]

5. In your Xamarin Forms iOS project (YourProject.iOS) paste the file GoogleService-Info.plist in the main folder.

[image]

6. Follow the steps of the **Setup** section on the [official documentation](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore) for both platforms (Android/iOS) and enjoy using it.

---

IMPORTANT: If you haven't authentication for your cloud Firestore database, you can setup its rules like the below image:

[image]