# Linking Xamarin Forms to Firestore

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a issue with linking Xamarin Forms to Firestore. I have a collection called Candidates in my Firestore Database in Firebase, and I am using the Plugin.CloudFirestore nuget to link Firestore and Xamarin Forms

I have tried using the 'Get' example on the following link:

https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore

```
        var query = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                    .Instance
                                    .GetCollection("Candidates")
                                    .GetDocumentsAsync();


        var documents = query.ToObjects<Candidate>();
```

When I run the code I get the following message

**"Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [FirebasePlugin] doesn't exist."**

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have google-services.json in the main folder?. You can take a look at these instructions before work with Plugin.CloudFirestore https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418014/5869384

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instruction?

- Add google-services.json to Android project. Select GoogleServicesJson as build action. (If you can't select GoogleServicesJson, reload this android project.)
- Target Framework must be Android 9.0 (Pie). Multi-Dex needs to be enabled if you use other libraries, Xamarin.Forms etc.

  ```
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
  ```

https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore#android

Comment: Yeah, I followed the instructions. Still not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Maybe I have to add my Firebase App name somewhere but the tutorial doesn't say where.

Comment: https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore/issues/1#issuecomment-496042135 is similar as yours , try to call Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestore.Init();

Comment: Okay, I have added Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestore.Init(Application.Context); but now i get: Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.zzehy' on a null object reference