# Xamarin Form .iOS connecting with Cloud Firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-cloud-firestore

please need assistance in finding document/training/book that helps with setting up xamarin forms (iOS) to cloudFirestone.

Googled it for a while now but not getting proper information. Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149921/example-to-integrate-firestore-in-xamarin-forms-andriod-ios) may help.

Comment: In addition to @Jack Hua, [this github repo](https://github.com/yamachu/Sample-Firebase-Cloud-Firestore-Xamarin.Forms) might work: Sample project to use Firestore by Xamarin.Forms

Comment: You can take a look at these instructions before work with Plugin.CloudFirestore https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/60418014/5869384