# Connect Xamarin with Google Firebase using Google.Cloud.Firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a Xamarin Application using Google Firestore as db.
I connected my app to db by setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as Environment Variable
but when I try to read data from db I get this error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")
  at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2[TRequest,TResponse].MoveNextCore (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00406] in /_/src/Grpc.Net.Client/Internal/HttpContentClientStreamReader.cs:194 
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1[TResponse].MoveNextAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00032] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/AsyncResponseStream.cs:71 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Action`1[T] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007a] in /_/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ForEach.cs:41 
  at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Action`1[T] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00140] in /_/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ForEach.cs:41 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.GetSnapshotAsync (Google.Protobuf.ByteString transactionId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00090] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Query.cs:681
```

and this is the code I'm using

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await databaseFS.Collection(myCollection).GetSnapshotAsync();
```

Is Xamarin compatible with Google.Cloud.Firestore and Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1?
If yes, why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Xamarin is compatible with Google Firestore. [Do Xamarin support Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838615/do-xamarin-support-firebase-cloud-firestore)

Comment: @Spack09, did the previous comment address your concern? If so, please post it as answer so that other community members with similar question will find this helpful.

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm still looking for the solution

Comment: See this issue with the same error: [Why does Xamarin Android fails to send GRPC/Http2 requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360430/why-does-xamarin-android-fails-to-send-grpc-http2-requests)